# mongoose multiple reference to single field and populate same type of two fields together

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

```
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 
 const userSchema = Schema({
     helper_member: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'onModel'},
     sponser_member: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'onModel'},
     onModel: {
       type: String,
       required:true,
       enum: ['user','admin']
     },
   
   });
   const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
   module.exports = {User} ;
```

```
find().populate('sponser_member helper_member',{ _id:0,full_name: 1,user_name:1,designation:1,earnings:1})
```

I have tried this but no use

so how can I do this if I have multiple fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not very sure what the problem is but try this:

```
const result = await User.find({}).populate("helper_member sponser_member")
```

This should find all users in the database and populte the fields by reference.

Also make sure that the reference does actually exists.

Comment: yeah that was the probelm the i dont save the collection name as a string on the corresponding onModel field